# How to share project with Visual Studio 2012 Professional and TFS (visualstudio.com)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have opened an account and created a project on visualstudio.com. I have connected my VS 2012 to TFS. However, when I try to add project to source control, I always get SourceSafe window and can't seem to find an option to share project with TFS. In Team Explorer I can see project I created, but no way to upload the code?

Comment: What do you mean by sourcesafe window? I can add projects to TFS.

Comment: I get this problem only on the machine where SourceSafe was used previously. When I try to share the project, a SourceSafe client window is shown where I can initialize new or use existing repo.

Comment: What do you mean by share the project? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Have you uninstalled SourceSafe? Have you verified whether TFS command can work? such as c:\projects>tf add test.cs; c:\projects>tf checkin

Comment: I haven't uninstalled SourceSafe, I need both for the moment. You mean to say I can't use TFS if I am using SourceSafe?

Comment: Did this work for you? Did you try the steps I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: The computer in question is at my workplace and I am not going back until next week. When I am able to try I will let you know, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `File --> Source Control --> Advanced --> Change Source Control` and make sure all the bindings are correct (i.e. connected to `TFS` and not `Sourcesafe`). You might have to unbind and bind back again. You don't need to uninstall Sourcesafe.

Also, look at your workspace (`File --> Source Control --> Advanced --> Workspaces`) and see if its bound to the correct source control folder.